# Prove the set of all subseq $(p_n)$ is is all of $\mathbb{Q}$ for $(p_n)$ whose range is $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm trying to prove that for $(p_n)$ whose range equals Q, then the set of
subsequential limits of $(p_n)$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$

I understand $p_{n_i}$ is a subsequence of $p_n$ and if $p_{n_i}$ converges, then its limit is called a subsequential limit of $p_n$. I also know from a theorem that the subsequential limits of a sequence in a metric space form a closed subset of X. However, I have no idea how to even begin this proof. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The roles of Q and R in the title are the reverse of what they are in the body of the question. Please edit for consistency. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\mathbb{Q}=\{p_1,p_2,p_3,...\}$. Now take $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and we have to show that there is a subsequence $(p_{n_k})$ of $(p_n)$, which converges to $x$.

To this end observe, that each intervall in $\mathbb{R}$ contains infinitely many rational numbers.

Hence, in $(x-1,x+1)$ there is a number $p_{n_1}$. 
Since $(x-\frac{1}{2},x+\frac{1}{2})$ contains infinitely many rational numbers, there is $n_2>n_1$ with $p_{n_2} \in (x-\frac{1}{2},x+\frac{1}{2})$.

And so on ...

We get a subsequence $(p_{n_k})$ of $(p_n)$ with

$$|x-p_{n_k}| <\frac{1}{k}$$

for all $k$.

Comment: Thanks! This was very intuitive. Out of curiously, would we be able to apply the theorem that $p \in X$ is a subseq limit iff $\forall \epsilon >0, p_n \in N_(\epsilon) (p)$ for infinitely many values of n? Would this make the proof more rigorous?